# ImagePicker Crash Flutter 1.22.1

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using the following code to pick images from both Camera and Gallery.

```
Future<File> getImageFromGallery() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

_image = File(pickedFile.path);

return _image; }

Future<File> getImageFromCamera() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

_image = File(pickedFile.path);

return _image; }
```

Used Package

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

Everything was perfect until I updated flutter to version 1.22.1
After that when I pickup an image the app crashes without any specific error, all I got is

> Lost connection to device

Thanks

Comment: On which device your app crashed

Comment: Nexus 5 "Emulator" API 27 @manpreetsinghpandher

Comment: This should be the permission issue.You need to  ask the permission manually using permission_handler plugin

Comment: Still Not working, I tried on new emulator it worked for the first time then the problem returned @manpreetsinghpandher